# Javascript Onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to achieve a very simple effect to scroll divs when pressing an arrow button ... How do i do this?

Basically i have a maximum of 4 divs named:

Slideframe, slideframe1, slideframe2 and slideframe3

I have a PHP variable called count which generates the slideframe content based on a PHP loop which increments a variable called $count.

Therefore the count variable can be between 0 and 3.

I want buttons to scroll divs left and right based on the count variable
If the count variable is 0 then no scroll buttons would appear.
If the count variable is 1 or 2 then both left and right scroll buttons would be visible and woudl scroll the relevant divs.
lastly if count = 3 then only a left arrow would be visible.

this is the javascript i use (in conjunction with jqmin liibary) to move the divs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

 $("#one").click (function(){
          if (navi =1){
 $(".slideframe").animate({opacity: "0.1", left: "-=960"}, 1200);
 $(".slideframe1").animate({ left: "-=960"}, 1200);
  }
 }); 
});
```

"#one" = the id of the left arrow image.

Whats the simplest way of doing all of this?

thx

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of existing slider plugins and tutorials for jQuery. I suggest you check out:

[13 Super Useful jQuery Content Slider Scripts and Tutorials](http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/13-super-useful-jquery-content-slider-scripts-and-tutorials)

[25 jQuery Image Gallery/Slider Tutorials and Plugins](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/)

Comment: They rarely deal with a seperate php variable and im a complete noob .. i will look at them again though

Comment: Also i have tried multiple plugins and they never worked how i wanted, thats why i wrote my own up to this point....

Comment: I don't think the PHP side is that relevant. Your PHP should just render some HTML (say as an unordered list) that the jQuery then acts upon.

Comment: unfortunatly not, the php renders a loop which draw, dates, time, images. title and text into various divs, to create multi-layed "panes" of data from a CMS..... thats why the <ul> strategies wouldnt work for me (or maybe i just didnt understand enough at the time)